# Git plug in for aptana studio

Tags: git

I need a Git plugin for Aptana studio.

I used http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates for Eclipse. It works fine.

How about Aptana?

Thank you.

Comment: Aptana has Git built in.

Answer (score 3):

The Aptana built-in Git integration relies on a native Git installation. If you don't want that, you can also use EGit with Aptana, since Aptana is based on Eclipse.

Comment: If you want to use native git installation, if need to specify where is the git executable by going in Preferences > Team > Git